# MemcachedClient Performance using its get method

Tags: java, memcached, spymemcached

I have some value in memcached, 500,000 for example.
When I try to fetch a particular value with its key, and using its get method. It takes random time like 20 ms, 5 ms and so on. Sometime around 500 ms.

Is memcached this much slow ? Or is there any way to improve its performance? I test time by the following way. I have printed the System time in ms before fetching the value and after fetching the value.

```
 System.currentTimeMillis();
 memcachedClient.get("key");
 System.currentTimeMillis();
```

If i set some values in the memcached and try to get a value from them in the same run. then i will be getting more time.But if i will do these task seperatly i'll get less time for fetching. why?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not that slow. It only depends on how your system is set up.

First question is: where is your memcached? Is it a local memcached (on the same machine than where you executed this java code) or is it a remote memcached?
If it is remote, then you need to know what is the latency between your box and the remote one (500 ms is a lot though).
Also, what else runs on the box on which you execute the java, and what else runs on the box on which memcached is running?

memcached is fast so that's a problem with your configuration... You need to investigate and provide a lot more information if you want to us to help you.

Also, when you use a external lib (spymemcached here), please provide its version (2.8.12 I assume). Sometimes, there are known issues with a particular version (but it won't be the case here).

Comment: I am executing my java code on my local system itself and memcached is also on local system. I have allocated 1Gb for memcached while installing it.Just now i have closed all other application running on my system and Run the test. Now I am getting values around 10 ms. But not a particular value.

Comment: Just help with how much time it takes to get a value from the cache in ms.

Comment: does it take random time value always to get the value from the cache?